# Joomla JDatabase: selectRowNumber strange use of class attribute or method

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, joomla

in Joomla 3.9.16 there is a strage use of a class attribute that is also used as a method!

In libraries/joomla/database/query.php you can find:

```
protected $selectRowNumber = null;
```

but also

```
public function selectRowNumber($orderBy, $orderColumnAlias)
{
  $this->validateRowNumber($orderBy, $orderColumnAlias);
  $this->select("ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $orderBy) AS $orderColumnAlias");

  return $this;
}
```

You can undestand why reading this method of the same class:

```
protected function validateRowNumber($orderBy, $orderColumnAlias)
{
  if ($this->selectRowNumber)
  {
    throw new RuntimeException("Method 'selectRowNumber' can be called only once per instance.");
  }

  $this->type = 'select';

  $this->selectRowNumber = array(
    'orderBy' => $orderBy,
    'orderColumnAlias' => $orderColumnAlias,
  );
}
```

When you call `$this->selectRowNumber()` as a method for the first time, it calls `$this->validateRowNumber()` in which `$this->selectRowNumber()` becomes an array!
If you call again `$this->selectRowNumber()` it throws an exception because you can call it only once and is no more a method.

I wonder if this is a good programming practice, I think definitely NOT because is not easy to understand and mantain. Maybe you can achive the same result in another way much more clear and linear.
What I ask is: am I right or this is a common practice?

Thanks

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you can reproduce this fault?  I am going to assume that you are misreading the script.

It looks to me that the `selectRowNumber()` method is called the first time and then inside `validateRowNumber()`, the class variable/property `$this->selectRowNumber` is checked for truthiness.

Since it is `null` (falsey) the first time, no exception is thrown.

The class variable/property (not the method) is updated with

```
$this->selectRowNumber = array(
    'orderBy' => $orderBy,
    'orderColumnAlias' => $orderColumnAlias,
  );
```

Then back inside `selectRowNumber()`,
the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $orderBy) AS $orderColumnAlias` string is applied to `$this->select()`.

Because `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $orderBy) AS $orderColumnAlias` must not be applied twice to a given query, the safeguard / thrown Exception checks for a truthy class variable/property -- which of course it is because it has been modified from `null` to a non-empty associative array.

Is it confusing to have properties and methods sharing the same name? Sure.  The only distinction between the two is the trailing `()`.

Is this acceptable coding practice?  Well, in terms of readability it's not ideal.  But once a project standardizes its naming convention, sometimes these kinds of converging names happen.  The bigger the code base, the more likely this is to occur.  I think consistency is more important than readability in this isolated situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No it's not a fault, this code works, my question was only about code readability. I'm doing a port in NodeJS/mysql2 of this class so I wanted an opinion on that method.

Comment: Have I sufficiently clarified that the method does not become an array?  The property goes from `null` to an array.  Asking why code is written a particular way (by other developers) borders on being off-topic: opinion-based ...so just be aware of this in the future when asking a question on Stack Overflow.  If I have resolved your question please award the green tick.  If not, please tell me what else needs to be addressed.